# loading an ajax call in a while loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with calling a function in a SQL while clause and can't for the life of me get it to run for each row that is displayed.

```
while( $Trow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Tresult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){

TaskIDX: <?php echo $Trow['IDX'] ?>
<br>
begin get assignment 1
<div id="Assignments-<?php echo $Trow['IDX'] ?>" data-id="<?php echo $Trow['IDX'] ?>)"></div>
<script>

    $(".Assignments").each(function() {
        var Task_IDX = $(this).attr("data-id");
        GetAssignments(Task_IDX);
    });

    function GetAssignments(Task_IDX) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetchesforajax/fetch_assignments.php",
            data: {Task_IDX: Task_IDX},
            success: function(html){
                console.log(html)
                $('#Assignments-'+Task_IDX).html(html);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
<PHP } ?>
```

And this from the fetch_assignments.php (for now)

```
$Task_IDX = $_POST['TaskIDX'];

echo 'this is an echo: ' . $Task_IDX;
```

This is the result. As you can see, it makes the call on the first run but not on the subsequent. It also does not echo the Task IDX.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You've set the `id` as `Assignments`, yet your jQuery is using a class selector... I don't see how this is working at all? Also note that making AJAX requests in a loop is a really bad idea. Create an array of the ids and send them all in a single request, then handle the response for all elements in UI from the response.

Comment: Where is the while loop? Do you mean `$.each()`? Or is there a PHP loop around all this code?

Comment: Edited to include modifications and clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here, based on some mistakes in the code in the question.

Firstly, it seems that you're creating multiple `#Assignmments` elements in the DOM given that you're using an `each()` loop to iterate them. This is the main cause of your problem. When you use an `id` selector in the DOM, only the *first* element with that `id` will be returned. This is because `id` must be unique; you cannot apply the same `id` to multiple elements.

The jQuery code you've got is then trying to use a class selector to select those elements, but that will have issues too as it will update *all* of those elements, not the one related to the AJAX response.

The quick and dirty fix to this is to pass a reference to the `.Assignment` element to the function which makes the AJAX request:

```html
<!-- in your PHP loop... -->
<div class="assignment" data-id="<?php echo $Trow['IDX'] ?>)"></div>
```

```js
$(".assignment").each(function() {
  var taskId = $(this).data('id');
  GetAssignments(Task_IDX, $(this));
});

function GetAssignments(taskId, $assignment) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetchesforajax/fetch_assignments.php",
    data: {
      Task_IDX: taskId
    },
    success: function(html) {
      $assignment.html(html);
    }
  })
}
```

This will work, but still has the underlying problem that you are flooding your server with requests.

A better approach would be to build an array of all the `data-id` values and send a single request to the server. The response to this request would include all the data for each element, ideally in JSON format, ready for all the `.assignment` elements to be updated in one loop.

Note that this would require amending how your `fetch_assignments.php` logic accepts and returns data, which I'll leave to the OP to research as I'm not a PHP developer, but the JS would look something like this instead:

```js
function GetAssignments() {
  let assignmentIds = $('.assignment').map((i, el) => el.dataset.id).get();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetchesforajax/fetch_assignments.php",
    data: {
      ids: assignmentIds
    },
    success: function(response) {
      // assuming that 'response' is an array of 'assignment' objects:
      response.forEach(assignment => {
        // create/update the HTML as required here...
      });
    }
  })
}
```